# vba set array value to NaN

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, nan

I work with double array which are partially filled with data and then printed to a range in a n excel sheet.

The problem is, that all values are by default 0. I would want them to be NaN (not a number), which is represented in the cells as NV(). The double array should convert to NV() automatically if possible.

Comment: `=NV()` in Excel raises the `#NAME?` error value.

Comment: NV() is German for NA(): http://office.microsoft.com/de-de/excel-help/nv-funktion-HA102752925.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring your Array as double just maintain it as variant

Then you can initialize the Array with `#NA` using [CVErr(xlErrNA)](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx)

```
Sub MyInitializer()
Dim Arr(10)

'Initialize all values to #NA
For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
Arr(i) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Next

'Do something with Arr values
Arr(1) = 2.5

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Range("K1")
Set Destination = Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr), 1)
Destination.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub
```